# Programmatically accessing @JsonProperty from Java

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following POJO using Immutables+Jackson under the hood:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
abstract class AbstractQueryRequest {
    @JsonProperty("reqid")
    public abstract String reqid();

    @JsonProperty("rawquery")
    public abstract String rawquery();
}
```

At some point I need to build another object based on the fields of the POJO, something along this line:

```
    final HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(cfg.baseUrl()).newBuilder();
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("reqid", request.reqid())
            .addQueryParameter("rawquery", request.rawquery());
```

It's quite annoying to keep the POJO and this call aligned upon changes, I was wondering if it was possible to access programmatically each JsonProperty instead of typing the string manually.

Note that it is fine to write the getters by hand as I can easily refactor and I have the compiler double checking, but for strings I am worried for people down the line and I would like to "read" them from the POJO class somehow.

Comment: Have you tried using reflection to get all (public) fields on the class, then get the `JsonProperty` attribute on each one? [How to get fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) of type [Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via reflection. You need to take method annotation values which annotated with **JsonProperty**. But I recommend you to use JsonProperty on fields, not methods.

Here is an example for your current requirement :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractQueryRequest someType = new SomeType();

        for(Method method : x.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class)) {
                JsonProperty annotation = method.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
                System.out.println(annotation.value());
            }
        }
    }
}


class SomeType extends AbstractQueryRequest {

    @Override
    public String reqid() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String rawquery() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
rawquery
reqid
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Just to understand, why are you suggesting not to use such annotations on methods rather than fields?

Comment: Does your methods guarantees the return values while serializing? It may have some validations it may throw exceptions etc. Using on fields mean saying that "I have thoose fields and I want them to serialize or not serialize". However it also depends on implementation details and use cases. There is not strict rules.

Comment: Those methods will be used by Immutable lib to create associated fields, and they act just as getters, so w.r.t. your comments it should be fine

Comment: I'm glad to help you